# MS SQL Server How to find Linked Server IP address and local instance

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I've inherited a linked server and would like to access the server and db\instance locally. I suspect the linked server isn't necessary and a better solution might be available.

Problem is there is no documentation on the Linked Server and the person that set it up has long since left.

My question is:

How can I find out the IP address, machine name, SQL db and instance name(s) from the linked server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find destination IP address of a linked server in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055562/how-to-find-destination-ip-address-of-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: No it doesn't I'd already seen and read that page. I tried running this SQL with a small modification and it errors out. I was hoping there's another way to do some detective work and figure out which remote box the db is running on.

Comment: What's the error it throws?

Comment: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LSERV1" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
 I have tried to solve this error as well and gave up after my attempts failed.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer, especially if your linked target database is Oracle:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77098457/4960976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use

```
EXEC sp_linkedservers
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM sys.servers
```

To find more info on your current linked servers.

The error referencing `MSDASQL` suggests an issue with an ODBC (system) data source created on the server, so if you go to Control Panel->Administrative Tools-> Data Sources (ODBC) you might start finding your answers there.

Comment: I've run these and returned only the same server name. Interestingly in the SRV_PRODUCT col, 'Progress' is returned, not 'SQL Server' which I'd expect. I think I might be dealing with a non-SQL db server here...

Comment: Progress is definitely not the same as SQL Server ;-) but all kidding aside, this confirms what your MDASQL error suggested. Either way - looking up the ODBC configuration will aid you.

Comment: Definitely it is not :) I will continue investigating, thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Right click the linked server in management studio and generate a CREATE TO script and check the connection details.

Comment: I did this last night, but the info in it doesn't tell me stuff I don't already know. The @server name is "LSERV1", but I can't determine the IP address (or which server) this is actually running on! I need to know which machine it's on and can't believe it seems to be difficult info to get :(

Comment: How does the metadata look? Is that in fact the server name or some reference to some system DSN / ODBC or something?

Comment: There is no other useful info in the generated SQL. Simple the reference to the server name that I can't find on any other machine in our network!